# How can I fix this issue accessing Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, command-prompt

Every time I try to initialize  MongoDb by typing mongo it shows me this error of “not recognized as internal or external command” As most people would suggest to this question, I have set the environment variables as suggested, [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3WBy.png)yet still not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The program **mongo** was superseded by **mongosh** as of June 2020.

For Windows operating systems, there are two methods of installing the MongoDB Shell (mongosh). I recommend that you reinstall using the MSI package **Windows 64-bit (8.1+) (MSI)** [msi-download-link](https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongosh-1.5.1-win32-x64.zip). The download page is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell).

Once the installation is complete, reboot your system.

Comment: I currently have both Mongodb community server and Mongosh installed. So what you mean is that I only need to install Mongosh?

Comment: @Rick - Unless you have a reason to use old software, only install mongosh.